# want to compare two columns in excel with unique column using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am pretty new to python and been learning for past couple weeks now.
I want to compare two columns in excel with unique column using openpyxl.

Excel1:

```
Area_Code    Representative Name
1                 Jim
2                 Pam
3                 Mike
4                 Ryan
5                 Kelly
6                 Andy
7                 Robert
11                Roy
```

Excel2:

```
Area_Code    Representative_Name
1                 Jim
2                 Pam
3                 Mike
4                 Ryan
5                 Kelly
6                 Andy
7                 Roberto
8                 Oscar
9                 Angela
10                Packer
```

Area code is unique.
I want to be able to list Any typo's in 'Representative_Code'. For eg: Area code 7 is Unique, but in excel2, I have a difference in name from Excel1.
At the same time, I want to list rows that are in excel1 and not in excel2 and vice versa.

I have written below code, but am not able to achieve my requirements. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb1 = xl.load_workbook('Excel1.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb1['Sheet 1']


wb2 = xl.load_workbook('Excel2.xlsx')
sheet2 = wb2['Sheet 1']


for row1 in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):
    cell1 = sheet1.cell(row1, 2)
    for row2 in range(2, sheet2.max_row + 1):
        cell2 = sheet2.cell(row2, 2)
        if cell1.value == cell2.value:
            print(f' {cell1.value}, {cell2.value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Load ur data to dicts:

```
dict1 = dict()
dict2 = dict()
for row in range(2, sheet1.max_row+1):
    if sheet1['A{}'.format(row)].value:
        dict1[sheet1['A{}'.format(row)].value] = sheet1['B{}'.format(row)].value
for row in range(2, sheet2.max_row+1):
    if sheet2['A{}'.format(row)].value:
        dict2[sheet2['A{}'.format(row)].value] = sheet2['B{}'.format(row)].value
```

And now u can get what u want from this two dict:

```
diff_set_not_in_excel2 = dict1.keys() - dict2.keys()
diff_set_not_in_excel1 = dict2.keys() - dict1.keys()

intersection_set = dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()
for key in intersection_set:
    if dict1[key] != dict2[key]:
        print(dict1[key], dict2[key])
```

Of course ， u also can get `Representative_Name` value from the keys of differ_set.

Comment: Can you please explain, what this below code does?

if sheet1['A{}'.format(row)].value:
        dict1[sheet1['A{}'.format(row)].value] = sheet1['B{}'.format(row)].value

Comment: @Aditya It means :If the **Area_Code** value is not a NoneType value ,then load the values in **dict1** ,and **Area_Code** as the **key** ,**Representative Name** as the **value**